# What does the path "./../" mean?

Tags: html, directory, path

In an HTML file named `page.html` in a folder named `pages`, the following `<a>` is found:

```
<a href="./../index.html">Homepage</a>
```

The `index.html` file is in the root folder (one level before `pages` folder). I know that the path `../` means one level before the level of the current folder (the same as "return one folder"). But what does the `./` together with `../` means to reach `index.html` in the root folder?

Comment: `.` is the current directory. `..` is the parent directory. So `./..` is the parent directory of the current directory, which is the same as plain `..`. Either `./..` is a typo of `../..`, or the path have been automatically generated by code which could often lead to such paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be helpful to you for pathing:

```
/ is the root of the current drive;
./ is the current directory;
../ is the parent of the current directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done anything web related in a while but I'm pretty sure "./" means current page/folder you're on and as stated in your post "../" means one directory up,or could just be a typo for "../../" which means 2 directories up